# Difference in passwd and sudo passwd?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, ubuntu-18.04

I wanted to know what happens when i run passwd command with sudo. I get a prompt to enter new UNIX password? Which user password is being changed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` will cause the console authenticate yourself with your current user. Once done, `passwd` command will be issued, so once you successfully authenticated, `root`'s password is the one being changed.

If you just run `passwd` without `sudo`, the current user's password is being changed.

Comment: Additionally, if you `sudo passwd user1` then you will be changing user1's password rather than your own or root's.

Comment: Let's say you have a friend who accidently ran `sudo passwd` when they intended to run `passwd` on a system where the root user isn't allowed to log in.  What (if anything) needs to be done to "undo" your friend's mistake?  Is running `sudo passwd -l root` sufficient?